# Geth - synced block header number is higher than actual number of blocks

Tags: go-ethereum, rinkeby

I'm trying to sync my geth node with `geth --networkid=4 --fast --cache=512 --datadir="/Users/myname/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/"`, which appears to be working. However, my node is apparently syncing way past the number of actual blocks on rinkeby, which leads me to believe I'm not on the right network. My last line of output is

`count=2048 elapsed=561.414ms number=1578304 hash=1ff9ed…3df3b8 ignored=0`,

but rinkeby only has about 1150000 on the chain right now. I haven't seen in the docs where anything else needs to be configured and I've started with a fresh chaindata directory.

EDIT:
Console outputs:

```
> eth.blockNumber
0

> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 1272698,
  highestBlock: 1935572,
  knownStates: 2246772,
  pulledStates: 2244979,
  startingBlock: 0
}
```

Comment: What the output of `eth.blockNumber` and `eth.syncing` console command?

Comment: Hmm...eth.blockNumber is 0, which is odd, but eth.syncing shows my current block. Why is the highest block so much higher than what's represented in etherscan?

Answer (score 1):

> Hmm...eth.blockNumber is 0, which is odd, but eth.syncing shows my
>   current block. Why is the highest block so much higher than what's
>   represented in etherscan?

It's 0 because your database isn't synced.
It still under the sync process, also looks like you aren't on [rinkeby](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/) you're on [ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/).

Comment: Is networkid 4 not Rinkeby? You're right my blockNumber is now at 1935572, which is closer to Ropsten, but why am I not syncing with Rinkeby?

Comment: networkid 4 it's Rinkeby. I don't know why you're synced with the wrong network. Which version of `geth` you're using?

Comment: Version: 1.7.2-stable

Comment: Also, here's some output when I start my node:

`Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=4`

So it knows what I'm passing in.

Comment: I think I got it. Needed to use `--rinkeby` instead of `--networkid 4`

Comment: It's the same, the `chainId` or `networkid` 4 it's rinkeby.

Comment: the `--networkid=4` must be used with `--testnet`, `--rinkeby` it's just a shortcut for networkid and testnet options.

Comment: ahh...so the issue was that I was using `--networkid 4` but not also including `--testnet`.